# Multiple files for Kong configuration

Tags: api-gateway, kong, kong-plugin, konga

I'm planning to generate multiple Kong declarative files based on swagger yml. Is there a way to combine them into the one? The only option I see is to use Kong Deck, but it's not clear whether it works with DB-less mode. What's the good practice to organize Kong configuration for multiple microservices?

Comment: Deck is clearly the good tool for that, plus with tag should can be sure that a mircroservice is not impacting the configuration of another service

Comment: you have a quick explanation of how we did that here https://konghq.com/videos/from-native-microservices-to-full-api-gateway-adoption-in-a-hybrid-mesh-ecosystem-in-the-cloud/

Comment: @Ôrel interesting video! Thank you.